# Email2Case - Change Value on a Case when Client reply an email

Tags: apex, workflow, email2case

**Problem**:
We have email-to-case implement. So client send an email to abc@abc.com and Salesforce automatically creates a case, this triggers the `EmailMessage`. And the Case Owner sees the case and answer the client with a solution for his problem. But the client cannot do it and answer that email saying that solution not works, and when the client answer something I must change a value on case.

**My solution**(Working):
Workflow rule on `Email Message` with this formula:

```
AND( 
  NOT( ISBLANK( ParentId ) ), 
  Incoming = true, 
  (TIMEVALUE(CreatedDate) - TIMEVALUE(Parent.CreatedDate)) > 1000 
)
```

I don't like this workaround that I did, anyone know another way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Is Incoming field of Email Message on Workflow. This field is true only when you received an email from the user. Please refer below code:

```
Email Message: Is IncomingEQUALSTrue
```

Comment: Hello Anurag, thanks for your answer.
this `Is Incoming ` field is for prevent when I reply to the client changes the case value. But the problem is, when the case is created by email-to-case the  `Is Incoming ` is true. and also change the value. I don't want to change the value when the case is created.

Comment: I think that in this situation you can check the status field of a case. When case created through Email-to-case then case status could be new and you also put this check on your workflow. Once your support team start working on the case then case status should change. Now next time when user replied on an email then your workflow condition fullfill and you can perform your action. Hope this helps you

Comment: Yes, can be a solution. But I need to do this without depending on the status. But Thanks a lot for your answer.